# Having difficulties making a login form can someone see the code and see what the error is

Tags: vb.net-2010

Im having a major problem with my current login code everytime i type in the username and password which is saved to a microsoft access database it comes in with an error with

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Running Club.exe

Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification.

Public Class Login_Form

```
Dim loginerror As String

Public Function Login()

    Dim DBconn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim user As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim Username As String
    Dim userDB As String
    Dim passDb As String
    Dim userfound As Boolean

    DBconn.Open("Provider= microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source ='" & Application.StartupPath & _
                "C:\Users\Wing's\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Running Club 2\Running Club 2\bin\Debug\Running Club.mdb'")
    user.Open("Member Table", DBconn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)

    userfound = False
    Login = False

    Username = "username='" & TxtUser.Text & "'"

    Do
        user.Find(Username)
        If user.BOF = False And user.EOF = False Then
            userDB = user.Fields("username").Value.ToString
            passDb = user.Fields("password").Value.ToString
            If userDB <> TxtUser.Text Then
                user.MoveNext()
            Else
                userfound = True
                If passDb = TxtPass.Text Then
                    Me.Hide()
                    Running_Club_Interface.Show()

                    user.Close()
                    DBconn.Close()
                    Return True

                Else

                    loginerror = "Invalid Password"
                    user.Close()
                    DBconn.Close()
                    Return False

                End If
            End If

        Else : loginerror = "Your Username or Password is incorrect please check username or password again."
            user.Close()
            DBconn.Close()
            Return False

        End If

    Loop Until userfound = True

    user.Close()
    DBconn.Close()
    Return True

End Function

Private Sub BtnIn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnIn.Click

    If Login() = True Then
        Me.Hide()
        Running_Club_Interface.Show()
        MessageBox.Show("You have successfully logged in.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(loginerror, "login Message")

    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Here is the Code anything u can say please do since its really bugging me and i dont 100% understand where to go and how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance this pierced my eyes. It's kind of a late reply, but should serve as guide for people who have similar problems.

```
 "Data Source ='" & `Application.StartupPath` & _
            "C:\Users\Wing's\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Running Club 2\Running Club 2\bin\Debug\Running Club.mdb'")
```

Try:

```
 "Data Source ='" & Application.StartupPath & "\Running Club.mdb'")
```

The `Application.StartupPath` already takes you into your debug folder. It could be a problem related to that... Since I'm using kind of a similar login form...

Also, make sure to add the Access library reference by right clicking your project, and choosing "add reference..."

Also, change this:

```
                   user.Close()
                DBconn.Close()
                Return True
```

to

`User.Close()
        DBConn.Close()
        Return False`